# What does stepping over an await statement mean?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I'm trying to understand the tools of the trade.

Take this code:

```
function myFunction(a)      // line 1
{                           // line 2
    someFunction(a);        // line 3
    someOtherFunction(a);   // line 4
}                           // line 5
```

Here, if my debugger is paused at line 3, if I press the step over button, what happens is that `someFunction` is run, and then when it returns, the debugger is paused at line 4. This is similar to setting a breakpoint on line 4 and hitting run, but it's not entirely the same. This implementation of someFunction shows the difference:

```
function someFunction(b)
{
    if (b > 0)
    {
        myFunction(b - 1);
    }
}
```

In this case, setting a breakpoint on line 4 will break on a recursive call, and stepping over line 3 will not.

Now let's look at code with an async statement:

```
async function myAsyncFunction(a)  // line 1
{                                  // line 2
    await someAsyncFunction(a);    // line 3
    someOtherFunction(a);          // line 4
}                                  // line 5
```

Once again, I have my debugger paused at line 3. It's unclear to me what happens if I press "step over" here. Is it once again like setting a breakpoint on line 4? Or does the browser force the call to be executed synchronously in this case? Or does yet something else happen?

Neither seems entirely intuitive to me. One of the weirder things that would happen is clear from this implementation of someAsyncFunction:

```
function someAsyncFunction(a)
{
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 60000));
}
```

With this, the site would become user fully interactible for a minute, and then suddenly be paused by the debugger again. That's not the behavior I would normally expect from pressing step over!

On the other hand, that same implementation would cause even bigger problems if it were to force the function to execute synchronously: it would cause the browser to become completely unresponsive for a minute. So maybe I'm just missing something about this whole situation?

So my question is this: what exactly happens when I press step over when paused at an `await` statement?

I'm mostly interested in the large-ish browser engines (Firefox/Gecko, Chrome/Blink, Safari/Webkit). It's probably also interesting to know what Node does, even though the considerations there might be quite different (and not all my logic above makes sense without a browser). And in general, it's interesting if there is a consensus on this. But other engines or environments that I'm not thinking of might be interesting as well...

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: *"With this, the site would become user fully interactible for a minute, and then suddenly be paused by the debugger again."* Sounds right. Did you try it?

Comment: `await` is basically syntactic sugar for `.then()`, with the rest of the function in the callback function. But the debugger may hide this and perpetuate the illusion that the code runs sequentially.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it once again like setting a breakpoint on line 4?

Yes, although (at least with Chromium devtools and V8) with the distinction you mentioned in your question re `myFunction`.

*(Note: If the code is transpiled for obsolete environments that don't support `async`/`await` and you're looking at source via a source map, the debugger may not be able to do as good a job here as it would with the actual `async`/`await` code.)*

> Or does the browser force the call to be executed synchronously in this case?

It can't. Debuggers can bend the rules of JavaScript a bit, but can't force asynchronous processes to be synchronous.

> With this, the site would become user fully interactible for a minute, and then suddenly be paused by the debugger again.

Yes. If you try it, that's exactly what happens, because if you step over an `await`, you're stepping over to code that handles the settlement (fulfillment or rejection) of the promise `await` is awaiting. So it's perfectly reasonable for the code to run without any special handling until the promise settles, including being user-interactive. If you think about it, that's not a million miles off having a breakpoint inside an event handler. In that case, things run along merrily until the event occurs, then the debugger stops things.